# Object comparison for non matching attributes

Tags: plsql

I have two instances of nested tables containing the same custom object type.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_obj
IS
  OBJECT
  (
    obj_primary_key NUMBER,
    obj_var2        NUMBER,
    obj_var3        NUMBER,
    obj_var4        NUMBER,
);
/    

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE body my_obj
IS   
MAP MEMBER FUNCTION func_map RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN obj_primary_key;
END; 
END;
/


DECLARE 
TYPE t_collection_1 IS TABLE of my_obj;
TYPE t_collection_2 IS TABLE of my_obj;
BEGIN
....
END;
```

I've created a map member function that will return obj_primary_key for comparisons. This allows me to perform Multiset Except statements between the two based off the "primary key" field. I perform this step to know which records in t_collection_1 need to be created in post processing to match t_collection_2.

My problem is I also need to know which records exist in both objects BUT the non mapped attributes don't match. This set will receive an update during post processing. Is there a PL SQL way to handle this (similar to Multiset Except) or will I need to take this into the SQL layer?